# Default CSS of Android WebView

Tags: android, css, webview, customization

I was wondering if it is possible to customize the default CSS file of the `Android` `WebView`.

I am already using a custom 404 page in my app, but the I also need to edit the CSS file of the default `WebView`. Andy ideas?